# Getting Grails not to create packages from hyphenated app names

Tags: grails, package, hyphenation

If I create a Grails app called a-b-c-d, doing a `grails create-domain-class User` will result in Grails creating a class User in the sub-directory grails-app/domain/a/b/c/d, giving it the package a.b.c.d. How do I prevent Grails from creating these package names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use packages, but you can customize the default package by changing the value of `grails.project.groupId` in Config.groovy. The default value is `appName` which is your application name, but you can change it to any value package, e.g. `'com.foo.bar'`.

In addition you can specify the package when running a create script, and if you do want to create classes in the default package, you can use this syntax:

```
grails create-service .Person
```

and it won't use a package.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, this sounds like a bug. There are two obvious workarounds

- change your app to have a name without dashes
- don't use the Grails commands `create-domain-class`, `create-controller-class`, etc. I never use these commands because they don't actually do anything other than creating the class (and a corresponding empty test class). Personally, I find it easier just to create the class myself than to run the Grails command

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the package when you call the cli command...

```
grails create-domain-class your.package.name.User
```